# BatchJobs in R: serialization is too large to store in a raw vector

Tags: r, parallel-processing, batch-processing, lsf

I am using the `BatchJobs` package. I have a list of `data.table` that I am trying to iterate over and submit jobs. However, i receive the following error message:

```
batchMap(reg, function(dtb) dtb[,roll_reg(.SD),by=gvkey], dtb_input_list)
Error: serialization is too large to store in a raw vector
```

Each `data.table` is about 7,000 rows and 6 columns.  I cannot seem to understand why this would be too large to serialize.  Every search comes up with numbers of 2^31 - 1 as the limit. Here is an example:

```
require(BatchJobs)
reg <- makeRegistry(id="myreg", file.dir="myreg")
test_list = lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame(a=rep(i,10000)))
batchMap(reg, function(dtb) nrow(dtb), test_list)
Error: serialization is too large to store in a raw vector
```

EDIT: Pending more investigation. This seems to be an error that comes in goes using the same exact data. Trying to understand what other environment variables are changing.

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Comment: Your example has `data.frame` not `data.table`. Are you using these terms interchangeably, or do you mean `data.table`?

Comment: @mnel: i just showed that it wasn't a `data.table` issue (i was getting the same error with `data.frame`). some is up with my system though because sometimes the above example works fine and other times it does not. trying to diagnose